# SOFU/ SE Reputation Aggregator

Tags: support, app-request, script-request

Is there an app that aggregates all my SOFU/SE reputation, badges in one single place?

I'm going to love it.

Answer (score 1):

There are different aspects of your suggestion built into various apps, but if examined in isolation, what would you want something like this to look like?

I don't mean "the button should be cornflower blue", I mean how would you envision the data being displayed/organized.

If you can describe it, it can be done. If you can't describe it, well......

Comment: I think I have only the vaguest idea of what I really want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a project to do this at [www.dao.af](https://www.dao.af). I'm open to suggestions.